Windows 11 PowerShell zip files except the excluded file and folder paths
I'm trying to zip using PowerShell but it's not excluding the files listed in the excluded_paths. I want to especially exclude all __pycache__ folder occurrences that can be nested in different levels of my python code base. Currently everything gets zipped including the files and folders that are supposed to be excluded.
$excluded_paths = @(
    "${parent_folder}/.vscode/*",
    "${parent_folder}/.git/*",
    "${parent_folder}/temp/*",
    "${parent_folder}/resources/documentation/*",
    "${parent_folder}/**/useful/*",
    "${parent_folder}/scripts/*",
    "${parent_folder}/*.template.*",
    "${parent_folder}/*TODO.*",
    "${parent_folder}/$(Get-Item -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).Name"
)

$exclude_pycache = Get-ChildItem -Path $parent_folder -Recurse -Directory -Filter "__pycache__" | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }

$excluded_paths += $exclude_pycache

Pause

$winrar_path = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"

#$exclusion_switches = $excluded_paths | ForEach-Object { "-x'$_'" }
#& $winrar_path a -r -ep1 $exclusion_switches "$output_zip" "${parent_folder}\*"

$exclusion_string = $excluded_paths -join ' '
& $winrar_path a -r -ep1 "-x$exclusion_string" "$output_zip" "${parent_folder}\*"

I tried this:
$exclusion_switches = $excluded_paths | ForEach-Object { "-x'$_'" }
& $winrar_path a -r -ep1 $exclusion_switches "$output_zip" "${parent_folder}\*"

and tried this one:
$exclusion_string = $excluded_paths -join ' '
& $winrar_path a -r -ep1 "-x$exclusion_string" "$output_zip" "${parent_folder}\*"

Even a simple example:
& $winrar_path a -r -x__pycache__ "$output_zip" "${parent_folder}\*"

does not work. It zips but it does not exclude all the __pycache__ folders.
Ok I tried
& $winrar_path a -r "-x*__pycache__*" "$output_zip" "${parent_folder}\*"

and that worked but the WinRAR documentation did not mention to quote it.
What am I doing wrong?

Actually, PowerShell has a zip feature. So there is no need to use third-party applications. Try Compress-Archive  in PS Command Line.  More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.4

Yeah I initially used that but it does not work if there are files "locked" or in use. That's why I opted for winrar

Don't use winrar.exe, but use rar.exe. Winrar.exe GUI. Rar.exe CLI

Try this. Editing is required according to your object.
pushd $PSScriptRoot
$exc_paths = @('.vscode', '.git', 'temp', 'resources', '__pycache__')
$exc_exten = @('.ps1')

$ToZip = GCI -R | ? {$_.Name -notin $exc_paths -and $_.Extension -notin $exc_exten}
$rar = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"
& $rar a -r $ToZip.Name
pause 

Using 7-Zip
$7z = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
& $7z a -r -aoa $ToZip.Name

Alternative
If there is only one folder to be compressed, just use CMD by make an additional text file Exclude.txt and write the files/folders name you want to exclude there.
@echo off
set parent="C:\temp\parent"
set SevenZ="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
%SevenZ% a -tzip archive.zip %parent% -xr@Exclude.txt
pause

Notes:

Replace set parent=.. variable with your parent folder
-tzip       : type of archive (7z, zip, rar, etc)
archive.zip : Archive name
Exclude.txt : List of files/ folders to be excluded,
separated by new line for each.
The Batch script outside %parent%, and Exclude.txt beside the scipt.

Content of Exclude.txt (Example):
_pycache_
.git
scripts
image.png

Faster using CMD. However, if you still want to use PowerShell:
$parent = 'C:\temp\parent'
$SevenZ = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
& $SevenZ a -tzip 'archive.zip' $parent -xr@'Exclude.txt'
pause


Hi thank you for sharing! It's a bit confusing I don't know which part is defining the name of the zip file? I want the name to be the value defined inside $output_zip

it doesn't do anything. it's just stuck at `RAR 6.23 x64   Copyright (c) 1993-2023 Alexander Roshal   1 Aug 2023
Trial version             Type 'rar -?' for help
Evaluation copy. Please register.`

You Should use Winrar full version https://karanpc.com/posts/

alternative use 7z free not paid

oh damn.. ok i guess i have to use 7z then. But that means another syntax again for the command oh man.. took me forever to figure out the one in my answer now i have to experiment again to figure out how to do it for 7z :(

WARNING: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
my_awesome_addon.zip

make sure close all files which will be compressed before processing

ok. its compressing now the files but there is a prob with the statement & $7z a -r -aoa $ToZip.Name it doesn't specify that i only want to zip the contents of the folder specified in  $parent_folder because now its zipping all the folders that are in the same directory as this folder. I tried $ToZip = GCI -R | ? {$parent_folder -notin $exc_paths -and $_.Extension -notin $exc_exten}

powershell is so confusing.. its not like bash. i just want to specify the target folder to zip. the target folder is $parent_folder. this is the target folder to zip and then we exclude some stuff. but i cant read the code and dont know where to insert this target folder in your code :(

in this screenshot https://snipboard.io/BUcu96.jpg my_cool_addon2 is the $parent_folder and the script resides in scripts/windows/build-zip.sh and the resulting zip file shall get generated 1 level above the parent_folder

it seems you are using windows inside Linux? not a complete windows OS.

ah yeah ubuntu app using Windows Linux Subsystem but the same path /mnt/d/ is accessible with D:\

What you need to pay attention to. If you are not using a full Windows OS, don't be surprised if some functions don't work.

thank you so much it finally works with your code. i really appreciate your help if only i could upvote this 10 more times :D

@Macky'sPrintingServices You're welcome. Sometimes I also need help in Linux from experts, because I'm a beginner.

Found the weird solution. If you want to recursively remove you have to redundantly define it like this -x*\scripts -x*\scripts\*. For files or folders with a dot use single quotes like .git folder.
& $winrar_path a -r '-x*\.git' '-x*\.git\*' '-x*.gitignore' -x*\__pycache__ -x*\__pycache__\* -x*\scripts -x*\scripts\* -x*\documentation -x*\documentation\* "$output_zip" "${parent_folder}\*"

okay windows is totally inconsistent now all of a sudden it doesn't work again. probably a windows bug

No. because you are still a beginner in Windows. you said it yourself. It takes time to learn it.

thanks. ok i fixed it. it's updated now :)

i noticed that when i use code block for my code it gets italized due to the asterisks.
